# Implicitly convert Geometry to WKT string in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, well-known-text, well-known-binary

Suppose I have a table defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE gtest (name varchar, geom geometry);
```

To insert, I am able to simply do this:

```
INSERT INTO gtest
VALUES (
    'Polygon',
    'SRID=4326;POLYGON((0 0,1 0,1 1,0 1,0 0))'
);
```

I don't have to wrap the WKT string in the function `ST_GeomFromText()` because PostGIS has an implicit cast that does so. This is nicely explained by @JGH [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54564452/does-postgis-automatically-convert-upon-inserting-wkt/54575108#54575108)

By using the PostgreSQL command `\dC`, the defined casts can be listed, including:

```
                                     List of casts
     Source type         |         Target type         |      Function      |   Implicit?
-------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------+---------------
text                     | geometry                    | geometry           | yes
geometry                 | text                        | text               | yes
```

I'd like to make it, so I can simply do a `SELECT * FROM gtest`, and have the results of the geometry column be implicitly converted into WKT. Currently, it will just display them as WKB.

First, I tried creating a new cast as follows:

```
CREATE CAST (geometry AS text) WITH FUNCTION st_astext(geometry) AS IMPLICIT;
```

This returned an error, since a cast from geometry to text already exists (as seen in the table).

I then tried `ALTER EXTENSION postgis DROP CAST (geometry as text);` and then `DROP CAST (geometry as text);`, and was then able to create the new cast:

```
                                     List of casts
     Source type         |         Target type         |      Function      |   Implicit?
-------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------+---------------
geometry                 | text                        | st_astext          | yes
```

This still didn't work however, as when I do a select, I still get the results in WKB.

Firstly, is this possible? Am I just doing something wrong?
Secondly, would any geometry functions break by adding this implicit cast?

Comment: Does this function work? https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsEWKT.html

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific as to what the end goal is? I see that you want to run "SELECT * FROM table_name;" and have it *display* the WKT format, but is that for a later export? or just to view it on the screen? the CREATE CAST function is not for what you have in mind here. your geometry data-type column must stay data-type geometry to perform any GIS with it.

Comment: @Marshall Basically I'm trying to retrieve data with a database driver in golang. Ideally, I'd like to just be able to query the column itself, without having to wrap it in a function, and have the result already be formatted in WKT format.

Comment: If you wish to query the column with no conversions, the column will have to be in text format. This means no more geometry functions. The only clean way I see of doing this is creating a new column of type text that stores a string of what was read from st_asText(geom) - basically a duplicate column that only stores strings of text. 
I'm not sure if this helps your goal, but I use the database GUI DBeaver and it automatically displays WTK with no prompting in its dataview tables.